# StencilJS: compile scss and copy to dist folder

Tags: stenciljs

My goal is to provide a css file in the distribution package which can be used by the consumer if needed.

For that I would like to create a kind of global scss file, but I want to avoid that this style is attached to each component + it also won't be used directly by the components. So for that I would like to create `my-style.scss` file somewhere in the `/src` folder.

What would be the best way to compile this file to `my-style.css` and copy it to the `dist` folder?

Comment: I don't think this is currently possible, as Stencil embeds styles in each component's JS based on whether it supports shadow DOM. I think you'd need to request external SCSS as a new feature.

Comment: @matthewsteele shouldn't this be somehow possible by running @stencil/sass plugin twice with rollup (in stencil.config.js). Until now I was not able to do the setup properly.

Comment: I don't think there is a way of doing that within the Stencil world. I'd probably setup a separate build task that compiles the file and poops it out to the dist folder separately from Stencil. e.g. `npm run build && npm run scss`

Answer (score 7):

It is possible to specify a global style with Stencil. Simply add the `globalStyle` property to your `stencil.config.js` and provide the entry `scss` file. Your config should look something like this:

```
const sass = require('@stencil/sass');

exports.config = {
  namespace: 'my-component-lib',
  outputTargets:[
    {
      type: 'dist'
    },
    {
      type: 'www',
      serviceWorker: false
    }
  ],
  globalStyle: 'src/globals/app.scss',
  plugins: [
    sass()
  ]
};

exports.devServer = {
  root: 'www',
  watchGlob: '**/**'
}
```

The build will successfully compile the scss to `dist/my-component-lib.css`.

Answer (score 0):

From the docs: https://stenciljs.com/docs/config/#copy

> The `copy` config is an array of objects that defines any files or
>   folders that should be copied over to the build directory. Each object
>   in the array must include a `src` property which can be either an
>   absolute path, a relative path or a glob pattern. The config can also
>   provide an optional `dest` property which can be either an absolute
>   path or a path relative to the build directory. Also note that any
>   files within `src/assets` are automatically copied to `www/assets` for
>   convenience.
>
> In the copy config below, it will copy the entire directory from
>   `src/docs-content` over to `www/docs-content`.

Within stencil.config.ts:

```
copy: [
  { src: 'docs-content' }
]
```

For example I am copying my css file from src to the build directory and it's totally standalone, e.g. https://github.com/BlazeUI/blaze/blob/master/packages/atoms/stencil.config.ts#L14